# Elasticsearch 1.5 can't find the plugin manager

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm currently trying to install the JDBC river on an 1.5 elasticsearch instance.

When running:

```
/bin/plugin --install jdbc --url http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.5.0.0/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.5.0.0.zip
```

I obtain the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager

Do you have any idea of the origin of the problem?

EDIT: I tried

```
bin/plugin
```

And get the same error, so it's not related to the url.

EDIT2: I'm using Windows.

Comment: I know that this might be dumb but try to run is with sudo...

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: I've just downloaded es 1.5.1 and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The url http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.5.0.0/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.5.0.0.zip is incorrect.

If you check the url http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.5.0.0/ in your browser, you will see there is no elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.5.0.0.zip file there. There is however a jar file of the same name. Perhaps you meant to use that one instead?

```
./bin/plugin --install river-jdbc --url http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.5.0.4/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.5.0.4.jar
```